# Vertically position tilde in LaTeX

Tags: tilde

I would like to have a tilde like this:

```
~some text
```

But it seems hard / impossible to easily achieve that in LaTeX.  Is it possible to have a "vertically centred" tilde which also looks like a "normal" tilde and is represented by that character so it is possible to search for it in the text?

Additionally I wanted to know why this seems so hard to achieve in LaTeX as that would help me understand the philosophy and mindset of LaTeX and to use it better and more efficiently.

My current effort looks like this but the tilde given by `\textsuperscript{\texttildelow}` is vertically too high.

```
the nation's \texttildelow $\sim$ \textasciitilde \textsuperscript{\texttildelow} 2,500 high complexity
```

[image: image of different tildes]

Comment: try `\raisebox{-0.9ex}{\~{}}`

Comment: `\testasciidilde` works in lmodern,as noted in the answers in the link in the comment above